# Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null why am I getting this error

Tags: javascript, html, javascript-objects, innerhtml, dom-events

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="demo">heoo</div>
  <script>
    var person = {
      name: "john",
      age: 50
    };
    var result = person.name;
    document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = result;
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

I want to display the person object property value into the div but it is 
showing can't set innerHTML to null.
Please give me some answers.

Comment: A class is not an id

Answer (score 3):

Change `class="demo"` to `id="demo"`

Or your code to:

```
document.getElementsByClassName('demo')[0].innerHTML= result;
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your class to id because you are using getElementById so

Getdocumentbyid will search based on ID

If you want to use by class then use like below

var y = document.getElementsByClassName('demo');
y[0].innerHTML= result;

Comment: Thank for your answer i am really proud of you guys thanks

Answer (score 0):

`document.getElementById('demo')` is trying to get an element from your Html document with an `id="demo"`. It'll not find any element in your Html because it doesn't have any element with `id="demo"`.

You can solve your problem by changing your `div` `class` to `id` (.i.e `<div id="demo">` instead of `<div class="demo">`), or by changing the way you're getting that element from javascript: `document.getElementByClassName('demo')[0]` instead of `document.getElementById('demo')`